# Clarification of the terminology: norm total

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me the definition of "norm total".  I can't find it.

Context:

Let $R$ be a Von Neumann Algebra.  Then the set of all projections in $R$ is norm total in $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $T$ is total in a topological vector space $V$ if its linear span is dense in $V$. So in this case, the statement is that the linear span of the projections in a von Neumann algebra is dense (in the norm topology) in the von Neumann algebra.
In symbols,
$$
\overline{\textrm{span}\ Proj(R)}^{\| \cdot \|}=R.
$$
Each element $x \in R$ is a linear combination of 2 self-adjoint elements.
Using the Borel functional calculus/spectral decomposition of self-adjoint elements of a von Neumann algebra, these self-adjoint elements can be approximated by linear combinations of projections.

The Borel functional calculus allows us to approach this problem by working with complex-valued functions on the spectrum of the self-adjoint element. The self-adjoint element corresponds to the function $z \mapsto z$, which can be approximated by step functions. But step functions are linear combinations of characteristic functions. By the Borel functional calculus, characteristic functions correspond to projections.